# Getting error "seek 32768 not supported with cursor 31952" using the CopyFilesOverSSH@0 Azure Pipeline task

Tags: bash, yaml, azure-pipelines, scp

I see solutions for this issue involving changing the chunk size and setting concurrency to 1 from 64, which is good because I am copying to an IBM product. However I am unable to figure out how to change these setting using the pipelines task. I am using a service connection so the only thing I see in the yaml is the guid for that connection. I would love to do the uplaod in my bash script but as yet cannot use ssh key pairs due to the archaic MS hosted agent and I can't figure out how to get it to recognize user/password credentials.

So if someone could show me how to connect to an ftp site in a bash script using an Azure Pipelines hosted agent or provide a solution for the chunking error, I would be eternally grateful.

Heads up, I am not a developer. I am a BA trying to get this thing migrated from Atlassian Bamboo, and we don't have a developer available to do the work.

yml export of the task.

```
- task: CopyFilesOverSSH@0
  displayName: taskUI
  inputs:
    sshEndpoint: c715e647-409c-4971-84ac-80b1a07e2049
    sourceFolder: /home/vsts/work/1/s/deploy/taskUI
    contents: '*.zip'
    targetFolder: /Inbox
    failOnEmptySource: true
```

Comment: I found sshpass in the listing of installed software on the agent and tried using the password again. The syntax worked (not sure what I did wrong before), but the response is wrong password. This is a known good password that I was able to login with manually. I copy/pasted, checked for leading/trailing spaces etc. So now what?

Comment: Forgot to add script details.

Script -- sshpass -v -p mypassword sftp -P 7022 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no BOT_CV@****.gov:/Inbox

Output -- 

SSHPASS: read: BOT_CV@****.gov's password: 
SSHPASS: detected prompt. Sending password.
SSHPASS: read: 

Permission denied, please try again.

Comment: the credentials used are the same as those used in the CopyFilesOverSSH@0 mentioned in the original question which does authenticate. Am I missing something? Is there a syntax error in this line? sshpass -v -p mypassword sftp -P 7022 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no BOT_CV@****.gov:/Inbox